# asp.net user control does no render when using https, works fine under http

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I just migrated a web site to asp.net 4, it seems to work just fine when I access it over http. However, when i switch to https my user control does not render.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's that user control about?

Comment: I'm referring to an ascx file (a.k.a. user control) that encapsulates some display information into a reusable hunk.

Comment: I know what a user control is :), I wanted more information about the problematic control. Obviously this is not a normal behavior and there must be something in the user control logic that can shed some light on the problem.